# VS2015 preprocessor Definition with dot

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, macros, preprocessor

I am working on a vs project, and in the Project -> Properties page, under c/c++ -> preprocessor, I have a preprocessor deff "$(USERNAME)TEST;". My username is "bob.p".

When building i get an intellisense error saying "command-line error: invalid macro definition: bob.pTEST". Removing the preprocessor definition or hard coding "bobpTest" without the dot resolves the issue. Is there some way of fixing this without removing the preprocessor definition? i.e. mark it as literal? tried using single and double quotes but neither worked.

edit:

The issue is that my windows username is "bob.p", and the visual studios project i am working on has "$(USERNAME)TEST" as a preprocessor defines. My username having a dot in it causes the error. Is there a way i can locally change the value of $(USERNAME) to remove the dot, or add an escape sequence to the definition to escape the dot?

Comment: You probably need something like `"\"$(USERNAME)TEST\""`

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please!

Comment: just tried using \" but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

A preprocessor symbol cannot have a dot in its name (remember this is the same as a `#define`), you can however do: `USERNAME=$(USERNAME)TEST;`

Using such a symbol (as a string) in the source is made a bit trickier by the way the preprocessor is handled, to use the value as a string you will need to use the preprocessor stringizing operator (#):

```
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

printf("My preprocesor symbol: %s\r\n", STR(USERNAME));
```